# Install CUDA 6.5 instead of 7.5

Tags: apt, cuda

I try to install CUDA 6.5 (CUDA 7.5 does not support my graphics card) and follow the steps in the getting start guide exactly.

```
$ sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1404_6.5-14_amd64.deb
```

3. Update the Apt repository cache

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get update
   ```
4. Install CUDA

   ```
   $ sudo apt-get install cuda
   ```
5. Perform the post-installation actions

However now cuda 7.5 is installed. How do I install cuda 6.5?

Comment: Apt-get installs the newest version of a package. If you specifically need an older version, download the package from packages.ubuntu.com and install it manually.

Comment: I downloaded the .deb file from https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-toolkit-65. But that is only 2.4kB and does not install it?

Answer (score 0):

From start:

Download above mentioned .deb:

```
wget -c http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1404/x86_64/cuda-repo-ubuntu1404_6.5-14_amd64.deb
```

Install it: `sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1404_6.5-14_amd64.deb`

Update apt: `sudo apt-get update`

Install with `sudo apt-get install cuda-6-5`

Answer (score -1):

Just type:

```
sudo apt-get install cuda-6-5
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.  Please expand this answer by [edit]ing it, and add the PPA this is coming from at a minimum (it's not in the default repositories)